# Изучение HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

Есть какая-то книга по изучению профессиональной верстки? Основные знание об CSS и HTML уже есть (к примеру, могу сверстать диз. к блогу).

Но меня интересует уже более лучший уровень. Хочется узнать, как делать верстку универсальной к маштабизации, полностью кроссбраузерною, правильное построение материки и все такое.

Comment: есть поиск на форуме. данный вопрос очень часто поднимался. от себя могу посоветовать книгу "Мастерская CSS" и всяческие издания с рецептами - "CSS. Рецепты программирования", "100 CSS рецептов"

Comment: [ПОИСК][1] ледчег ты опередил меня


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=%D0%98%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+HTML&t=question

Comment: @shrek, OHRLY? Думаешь, я не знаю, что такое поиск? Специально создал тикет, ибо не наше ничего нового.

Comment: qwerty123 лентяй.Пропиши поиск книги по верстке HTML CSS и не нужно врать

Answer (score 1):

Определенное время - даст определенный уровень!

Идем на [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru) учим html теги, атрибуты и их свойства. Синтаксис, свойства и значения css!

Книга не даст больше чем 90 страниц непонятной воды из 95 страниц всей книги, имхо!

Еще хорошо завистнуть тут [.](http://www.w3schools.com)[w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com)

Comment: За вторую ссылку спс :)
Я так понял, это сайт официального стандартизатора HTML?

Comment: И не только!